# tbl_summary, is there a way to compare categorical data by row as well as column? (Fisher's exact test; Pearson's Chi-squared test)

Tags: r, categorical-data, gtsummary

There are multiple categories in the table. Below I describe one variable as an example with the hope it can be applied across variables.

Currently, my code compares the columns female and male Food Control Score. However, there are two levels in the Food Control Score ("Normal", and "High"). Is there a way to also produce p-values for row-wise comparisons using a 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction?

```
con_tab<-ADE.Joined_tab %>% 
   dplyr::select(sex, `ADE Category`, `Food Control Category`, `Bingeing Category`, 
   `Body Control Category`, `Body Discontent Category`) %>% 
   tbl_summary(by = sex,
   statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
   digits = list(all_categorical() ~ 1)) %>%
   add_overall(last = T) %>%
   add_p() %>% 
   bold_labels() 

   con_tab

   con_tab$table_body %>% flextable()
```

Only shows column comparisons.

[image]